# Best way to resolve HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint in the service code

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Here is the question - how could I resolve http gateway port and protocol for a particular node type in my service code? So far I did manage to get this info only by parsing the app manifest like this -

```
var fabricClient = new FabricClient();

var appManifest = await fabricClient.ClusterManager.GetClusterManifestAsync();

var document = XDocument.Parse(appManifest);

var nodeTypeObj = document.Root.Descendants()
                               .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "NodeTypes")
                               .Descendants()
                               .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "NodeType")
                               .First(e => e.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Name" && a.Value == this.Context.NodeContext.NodeType));

var gateway = nodeTypeObj.Descendants()
                         .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == "HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint")
                         .First();

var port = gateway.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Port").Value;
var protocol = gateway.Attributes().First(a => a.Name.LocalName == "Protocol").Value;
```

Are there any simpler means to get these values? Something like a method I'd call passing node type along the way and getting back all the stuff that very node type is configured with? including HttpApplicationGatewayEndpoint?

Comment: Where are you going to use information about port and protocol?

Comment: Say I have a service that under certain circumestances needs to add another one to the running app. A new service is Guest Executable. And that first orchestrator needs to form a config for the guest process and pass locations of another services it requires along the way. By location I mean a reverse proxy(http gateway) endpoint, as I don't want to do all this 'resolve' voodoo in the guest service :)

Comment: So, I think your solution will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're scraping the cluster manifest - I probably wouldn't recommend going that far.

There isn't a specific API to get that information so I would either pick a port by convention and use it (the default 19008 would work), or put the port in an environment variable or a config package if you think it will change between environments.

Comment: But what if I'm planning to have multiple node types with the different gateway ports? And some of them but not all I'd want to secure... Specifying env variable per each scale set seems a little tedious to me. Parsing manifest gives some more generic approach... why do you think it might not be a good idea?